# What format are these paths exactly?

Tags: html, dom, web-scraping

I have several paths that I'm using to parse certain parts of an HTML page.

The following are several examples:

```
body > div > div.inner-wrap > div > div > div > div.person > div > a

body > div > div > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(1) > div.large-7.medium-6.columns > div > h1

tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td
```

I have seen a multitude of different format types for html nodes (e.g. IRB, Ancestry, CSS, Xpath <- although I think I've just discovered Xpath is specific to XML), and I'm a bit confused by exactly what I have in my examples above.

The reason I ask is because I'm looking for the best possible browser extension I can find to help me create these paths for scraping purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are CSS selectors. You might want to check out the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) about that topic. Also you don´t need a browser extension for that just inspect the element, right click and just copy the css selector (works in chrome and firefox)